# "PCA" based on distance metric other than $L_2$

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, distance

PCA is based on $L_2$ distance and is maximizing variance along the PC axes.

What if we try a different distance measure (something else than $L_2$)?
Do any methods corresponding to PCA but with different distance measures exist?
Can they be more useful than the vanilla PCA under some settings?

Comment: What exactly minimization or maximization is on you mind? Please note that classic PCA aims to _maximize_ variance (SS of deviations from the origin which is usually the centroid) _along_ the PC axes, not to minimize anything. It is strictly because the deal is about _squared_ deviations it appears (by pythagorean theorem) that PCA simulateneously _minimizes_ the squared deviations _from_ the PC axes - of what you are speaking. If comes to deal with nonsquared deviations then the two tasks will be separate aims.

Comment: @ttnphns, thank you for an enlightening comment. I am not sure what exactly I want from the method, but I am curious if something similar exists. Probably I want dimensionality reduction *a la* PCA but where the distance function is different. But that could be achieved by first doing some feature scaling and then applying vanilla PCA on the scaled data, I guess. I don't really know what I want here, but I am curious about any related ideas and their use. Maybe you could guide me towards a more precise formulation such that the question would be answerable properly.

Comment: I'm thinking, too, about some pre-processing (and this is _only_ immediate/intuitive, probably false idea). Here it is. Center the variables of X. Take sq. root of the values (their abs., then give them back their sign). Compute X'X/(n-1), that is, covariance matrix w/o new centering. Perform PCA. I don't know currently to what extent it will successfully maximize the Sum of abs. dev. along the PCs, but it might work.

Comment: Well it seems to me that mathematically  PCA amounts to finding orthogonal basis with respect to an inner product. Inner products are quadratic forms and quadratic forms always have a basis for which it's diagonal.  This is not my mathematical sweet spot, but I don't think you can produce distances compatible with the vector space structure except by L2.

Comment: Give a look at: [Generalizations of PCA: sparse features, loss functions (Everything you did and didn't know about PCA)](http://alexhwilliams.info/itsneuronalblog/2016/03/27/pca/#generalizations-of-pca-sparse-features-loss-functions)

Comment: You can't even get started unless you have something tantamount to *orthogonal projection,* because that is needed even to define what "distance along an axis" might possibly mean.  But the properties of orthogonal projection are compatible only with $L^2$ distances--each one can be used to define the other.

Comment: @whuber But is orthogonality tantamount to PCA? Most sparse-PCA algorithms do away with it.

Comment: @Firebug The issue isn't about the algorithm but about the very concept and meaning of PCA. If you can achieve a PCA, then--no matter how you have gone about doing it--you have used a Euclidean distance and its associated orthogonal projection.

Comment: @Firebug, whuber makes a good point. Regarding the link you referenced in your previous comment, this would concern the regularized estimation methods for PCA (sparse PCA, ridge-regularized PCA). But there is also logistic PCA in there which sounds like something I am asking about: it seems to be based on non-$L_2$ distance.

Comment: That's a fun question! (+1) I must have missed the first time it was posted!

Answer (score 1):

*"What if we try a different distance measure (something else than $L_2$)?"*

There are many ways of addressing that answer this question but the two obvious routes are:

1. "Norm/reconstruction-focused" approaches with[$L_1$-norm principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L1-norm_principal_component_analysis) being and obvious example we minimize an $L_1$ instead of an $L_2$ norm of the reconstruction error.
2. "*Specific* measurement types" i.e. model-based PCA (the most common being binary or count data but generally speaking in the exponential family). Collins et al. (2001) *"[A Generalization of Principal Components Analysis to the Exponential Family](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2001/hash/f410588e48dc83f2822a880a68f78923-Abstract.html)"* is the seminal reference here.

So for example, if we use $L_1$ we effectively have a more robust version of PCA such that the influence of outliers is amortised. Aside $L_1$, the "nuclear norm" (sometimes called [Schatten 1-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm)) is also used in a similar effect for denoising; I liked Gu et al. (2014) *["Weighted Nuclear Norm Minimization with Application to Image Denoising"](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2014/html/Gu_Weighted_Nuclear_Norm_2014_CVPR_paper.html)* as it was easy to follow and descriptive, the Wikipedia link contains a lot of signal processing references on this subject too.

Similarly, in a model-based PCA we minimise the divergence associated with the distribution at hand; Salmon et al. (2014) *["Poisson noise reduction with non-local PCA"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.0338)*, for example, shows a very nice application for Poisson data where the work out what is the appropriate [Bregman divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence) for their application. We need to note here that under model-based approaches matrix factorization is a by-product rather than a necessity.  We still compute projections obviously but in our "original space" these are projections are often non-orthogonal.

*"Do any methods corresponding to PCA but with different distance measures exist?"*

Yes, multiple ones as noted above; we don't even touch on the
[robust PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_principal_component_analysis) field where there is *a lot* of work there and even $L_0$ comes into play to promote sparsity. (So for example if we have both $L_1$ and $L_0$ we have versions of robust and sparse decompositions.)

*"Can they be more useful than the vanilla PCA under some settings?"*

Yes. Moving back to model-based approaches, when working on analysing questionnaires or datasets where the assumption of multivariate Gaussianity is obviously unfounded. I personally used this logistic PCA when working with symptoms data collected from medical databases where all my variables were indicators ("*Do you have symptom $x$?*") and we used Bernoulli deviance; the relevant reference for us was *["Dimensionality reduction for binary data through the projection of natural parameters"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.06112) by Landgraf & Lee (2020)*. I have also used probabilistic PCA as an imputation preprocessing step, I didn't find it great but it was a fun application too. From a reconstruction perspective, depending on your work, denoising use cases (as mentioned above) can also be quite relevant.

Comment: Thanks! There are a lot of things to look into here.

Comment: Pleasure! Yeah, I can appreciate that, I even deleted some stuff I originally wrote to somewhat contain the answer. I tried to touch succinctly upon all the subquestions.